# Bootstrap 3: 'padding' used for gutters, not 'margin'?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Why does Bootstrap use padding for its gutters instead of 'margin'?

The biggest annoyance I currently have with Bootstrap is that it requires any component on the screen to be wrapped inside another div if you want to use the grid layout.  For example, each of these [thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-default) must be wrapped inside another div; it can't just exist on its own.  You can't have:

```
<a href="#" class="thumbnail col-xs-6">...</a>
<a href="#" class="thumbnail col-xs-6">...</a>
```

You must have:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">...</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">...</a>
</div>
```

This is because the bootstrap grid model puts a gutter/gap between components by using the CSS "padding".  So to have two elements taking up 50% of the width of their container, Bootstrap will give each component's wrapper-div a width of 50% and padding of 15px.  Instead of having wrapper divs, why doesn't it just give the components a width of calc(50% - 30px) and a margin of 15px?  Surely the 'margin' is the more appropriate styling for putting a gap between two elements?  Is the big reason because IE8 does not support calc?

Bootstrap is great, but it is requiring me make my HTML uglier than I think it needs to be.

Comment: You can use Respond.js for IE-8 . Check documentation http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers

Comment: @NanduHulsure, I don't think Respond.js helps to support calc in IE8.  However this polyfill might: https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill